# Change file creation date to modification date using terminal

Tags: macos, command-line

So I have a bunch of pictures that have incorrect creation dates but their real creation dates are the same as the current modification dates. Is it possible to correct this using some batch command in terminal? I've been messing around with the setFile + stat commands but it's not really working out since I'm terrible with terminal. Does anyone here now the correct way to do this?

Also is it possible to incorporate this into a find command? So that all pics with "IMG" in them get this treatment but no others?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "creation date"? Is it the "Birth" date as shown by stat?

Comment: Yes the Birth date.

Comment: or the date set by setFile -d I'm assuming they're the same?

Answer (score 10):

To use @user3439894's answer with `find`, use the `-exec command {} +` clause, and put the for loop into a `sh` script:

```
find some/path -iname \*.img -exec sh -c 'for f in "$@"; do m="$(GetFileInfo -m "$f")"; SetFile -m "$m" -d "$m" "$f"; done' sh {} +
```

The 2nd "sh" will become the $0 inside the spawned shell, and the .img filenames will be the positional parameters $1, $2, ...

---

Not an explanation but a demonstration of "sh as $0"

Say you have a script like this, named `script.sh`

```sh
echo "$0"
echo "$1"
echo "$2"
```

Running it with some parameters gives:

```
$ sh script.sh first second third
script.sh
first
second
```

However, when you use `-c "$script_body"`, then the first argument slides into $0

```sh
$ sh -c 'echo "$0"; echo "$1"; echo "$2"' first second third
first
second
third
```

This is important because the special variables `"$*"` and `"$@"` takes the positional arguments starting with `$1`

Comment: Can anyone explain 'The 2nd "sh" will become the $0 inside the spawned shell' please? I understand that the filenames all populate `f` from `$@`, but where does the `sh` as `$0` come in? Thanks

Comment: @Chris, is that helpful?

Comment: Very helpful indeed, thank you! I also needed [this excellent answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/389706) to understand that `sh` could be any string, not necessarily the `sh` command, and `find` normally passes a filename at a time which is what `+` changes to many filenames in one call, and the `{}` is where find interpolates the filename/s. The second `sh` bit caused some head scratching!

Comment: For anyone else, [someone just told me](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705/understanding-the-exec-option-of-find/389706?noredirect=1#comment1473464_389706) that the string `sh` is used in error reporting, so the reason the second `sh` is always `sh`, even though it is just to use up `$0`, is because `sh` tells the reader that it is the `sh -c` command that generated the error message.

Answer (score 3):

If you have both `SetFile` and `GetFileInfo`, you can set the *creation date* to that of the *modified date* on `.IMG` files by doing the following:

In **Terminal**, first *change directory* `cd` to the location of the target `.IMG` files.

```
cd /path/to/target/files
```

Then execute the following *compound command*:

```
for f in *.[iI][mM][gG]; do m="$(GetFileInfo -m "$f")"; SetFile -m "$m" -d "$m" "$f"; done
```

---

**Note:** It is always a good idea to first test on a small sample of the *target files* copied to another folder and check the results first, then proceed on the *original files*. One should also always have normal regular backups as well before proceeding, e.g using Time Machine or other backup software.

---

If you do not have `GetFileInfo` and want to use `stat`, then directly after `do` replace:

```
m="$(GetFileInfo -m "$f")";
```

With:

```
m="$(stat -f'%Sm' -t "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S" "$f")";
```

Giving you the full *compound command*:

```
for f in *.[iI][mM][gG]; do m="$(stat -f'%Sm' -t "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S" "$f")"; SetFile -m "$m" -d "$m" "$f"; done
```

Note: This assumes you do have at least one `.IMG` file in the *directory*, otherwise it causes a non-fatal error, meaning nothing has changed:

```
stat: *.[iI][mM][gG]: stat: No such file or directory
ERROR: invalid date/time
```

To use `find`, see glenn jackman's answer.

Comment: I think you want your `stat` statement like this-> `stat -f'%Sm' -t "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S" FILE`.