# Change file creation date to content created date using terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, photos

I have a lot of pictures with the wrong creation date and wrong modification date.  There is however a third date, "content created" that is correct.  user3439894 had this command line as an answer to [Change file creation date to modification date using terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/359566/change-file-creation-date-to-modification-date-using-terminal)

```
for f in *.[iI][mM][gG]; do m="$(GetFileInfo -m "$f")"; SetFile -m "$m" -d "$m" "$f"; done
```

Where GetFileInfo reads the modified date and rewrites the created date.  Very useful and works great (after installing the command line tools) for a lot of my pictures that have the correct modification date, thanks.  What I am looking for now, is a syntax for "content created" date that I could use?

Any help on this would be great.

Comment: Adding a solution to the question itself is rather confusing, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers for ways to handle helpful answers.

Answer (score 5):

Using tools that are part of macOS, We start by getting the ContentCreationDate from the file and place it into a container `ccd` -

```
ccd=$(mdls -raw -n kMDItemContentCreationDate FILE)
```

Next, We format the ContentCreationDate string into a string usable by `SetFile` and place that into a container `nct` -

```
nct=$(date -f '%F %T %z' -j "$ccd" '+%D %T %z')
```

Finally, We use `SetFile` and set the FSCreationDate to the modified date/time string from ContentCreationDate -

```
SetFile -d "$nct" FILE
```

I'm assuming that you know how to place all of this into a loop for processing multiple files.

Note: Look into `exiftool`

Comment: Smart, here’s how to do the core part, well done and super clear answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I am a bit of a novice in Terminal, but followed up you advice on exiftool, which proved to be very good!  this simple line did the job:  exiftool "-FileModifyDate<DateTimeOriginal" *

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, this command works great to automatically convert both the "File Creation" and "File Modification" dates to the "Content Created" date.

```
exiftool "-FileModifyDate<DateTimeOriginal" *
```

But a little warning to those unfamiliar with the terminal, this command will do so to every file in the user directory by default. If someone has a specific folder they want to run this on, better to first use the "*cd*" command into the folder they want.

Alternately, you can just paste (not hit enter, just paste) the command without the asterisk into a terminal window:

```
exiftool "-FileModifyDate<DateTimeOriginal"
```

And **before** running the command, go back to Finder, select the files you want, and literally drag the files into the terminal window. It will auto-populate with the lists of files and then you can run the command, only affecting the files you chose.

Answer (score 1):

And for something totally different that uses only basic commands, you can do this:

```
# mv OriginalFileName.jpeg TempFileName.jpeg
# touch -t 199912310000 OriginalFileName.jpeg
# cat TempFileName.jpeg > OriginalFileName.jpeg
```

The basic system commands don't really want you messing with the creation date, because, well, *it is the creation date,* which should really be considered immutable!

(Why use `touch` when there are good examples here using `SetFile`? Well, the dates used by `SetFile` must be in the "Unix Epoch," which means they must be between 1970-01-10 and 2038-01-18. If that works for you, fine, but I have a lot of scanned photographs and PDF documents from before 1970, and `touch` will set creation dates outside of the UNIX Epoch, back to 1900. In addition, the formatting is tricker for SetFile, which does not use ISO Standard date/time formatting.)

So this solution basically copies the file, creates a file at a given point in time, then copies your original file's contents into the created empty file.

You can easily package this into a shell function and store in your .bashrc file for easier use:

```
function recreate {
    mv "$2" /tmp/file_to_recreate
    touch -t $1 "$2"
    cat /tmp/file_to_recreate > "$2"
}
```

Now you can simply type `recreate 199912310000 MyPhoto.jpg` and your function will "re-create" the file with the desired creation date.

The `touch` command with the parameter "-t" takes a date time in the following format: YYYYMMDDHHmm. You must enter all characters. Non-existent dates are silently accepted without error, and produce unpredictable arbitrary dates.

I use this for photographs, yes, but also I set the creation date to the copyright date on PDF books I collect.

I have a lot of scanned slides and photographs that don't have an internal EXIF creation date, so I haven't included updating EXIF data from the file creation date in my function.

Instead, I do the opposite: I use [GraphicConverter](https://www.lemkesoft.de/en/products/graphicconverter/download/), which has the best access to EXIF/IPTC data I've seen in any regular (non-Terminal) application. It can batch-set the EXIF internal creation date to the file creation date with just a couple mouse clicks.

Going the other direction — setting the file system creation date to the file's internal EXIF creation date — will require [exiftool](https://exiftool.org). This will allow you to extend the script above by obtaining the date you use in `touch` with a date from the image file, as supplied by `exiftool`.

To do that, replace the literal date string in the script above ("199912310000") with `exiftool -createdate -d "%Y%m%d%H%M%S" -s3`, surrounded by back-quotes.

Here's a new function for you that I've done just a bit of testing on. It takes one argument: the name of the image file to re-date.

```
function SetCreateFromExif {
    mv "$1" /tmp/file_to_re-create
    touch -t `exiftool -createdate -d "%Y%m%d%H%M.%S" /tmp/file_to_re-create` -s3 "$1"
    cat /tmp/file_to_re-create > "$1"
}
```

Comment: How does this read existing exif data from the file and use it in the update?

Comment: It doesn't. To do that, you'll need exiftool(1) for that. Type "man exiftool" to see more than you ever wanted to know about exiftool. Type "which exiftool" to see if it exists on your system — I don't think it comes with it. If you don't have it, it is best to get it via a package manager — my favourite is homebrew. Easy install directions for homebrew are at: http://brew.sh. After you have homebrew installed, you can type "brew install exiftool", and Bob's your uncle!

Comment: I just added some instructions for exiftool and GraphicConverter to the answer above.